# NoDefClassFoundError in Java

Tags: java, swing

```
public void setParent(Window parent) {
    if (true) {
        this.parent = ((abc.InvestRegPropertySeize) parent);
    } else {
        this.parent = ((cde.InvestRegPropertySeize) parent);
    }
}
```

In above when i compile this code it has succesfully compiled and after complition i manully delete the class file of 'cde.InvestRegPropertySeize' and when i try to run this code the follwing error is occuring.

```
NoDefClassFoundError of'cde.InvestRegPropertySeize'
```

But i think this should not be occur because condition always true and no need of 'cde.InvestRegPropertySeize' class file at run time then why it is occuring please tell me the solution.

Comment: Yes, you **need** the class file to use the class. Put it back. Or remove the usage of the [now missing] class. (It doesn't matter if the code is never run, resolving the referenced classes is done before it's executed.)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do something like this is by using [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html). Remove the two casts in your code, so the classes won't be resolved at runtime. Then use reflection to access fields and call methods. Reflection is powerful, but the code is not very readable and it comes with some performance overhead. So think twice before using it.